# Entity framework relationship broken

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have two models. `ApplicationUser`:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public DateTime AccountCreationDate { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ProfileView> ProfilesViewed { get; set; }
}
```

And `ProfileView`:

```
public class ProfileView
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime ViewDate { get; set; }

    public virtual ApplicationUser Viewer { get; set; }

    public virtual ApplicationUser Viewee { get; set; }

}
```

Entity framework seems to have created my tables correctly. I can do the following and retrieve a user's `ProfileViews`:

```
db.ProfileViews.Where(p => p.Viewer.Id == currentUser.Id);
```

My problem is that I can't seem to do the following:

```
db.Users
    .Where(u => u.Id == currentUser.Id)
    .Include(u => u.ProfilesViewed);
```

The above returns `null` for that user, even though it is a `Viewer` and a `Viewee` on several `ProfileView`.

I ran a `foreach` on all my users, none of them seem to have any `ProfilesViewed` if I query them from the `Users` table with `Include`. I can only retrieve `ProfileViews` from the `ProfileViews` table...

Anyone has any idea how to fix this?

Comment: more importantly, what is the PK for ApplicationUser? What is the mapping for this relationship?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you did not mention how the `ProfileView.Viewer` is related to the `ApplicationUser.ProfileViewed` EF thinks that they are not related(if you check your DB you can see another FK created in the `ProfileView` for the `ApplicationUser.ProfileViewed` collection). So adding instances to `ProfileView` does not effect the `User.ProfilesViewed`.

Add this code to the `Context` class, to specify that **each** `ApplicationUser` is related to **many** `ProfileView` through `ProfilesViewed` collection.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<ProfileView>().HasRequired(x => x.Viewer)
                .WithMany(x => x.ProfilesViewed);
}
```

Comment: You rock, it worked! Before whenever I'd created such models with virtual properties EF had automatically understood the relationship. I guess this one was a bit too unusual for it to make assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

The relationships probably need to be explained to be created correctly.  I think it's wrong because you have two relationships from ProfileView to ApplicationUser.  See the section "Configuring Unconventional Foreign Key Names" in [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh134698.aspx) for details of how to configure unconventional relationships using EF Code First.